# Ubuntu 14.04 won't start

Tags: boot

I have had Ubuntu 14.04 for a couple of weeks now with no problems.  Then suddenly, I started my computer up, logged into Ubuntu and it only showed my wallpaper.  There were no icons and the terminal didn't work.  I had made no changes to my computer and it was working fine when I logged in only an hour before.  I have a dual boot with windows 7 (which is working fine.)  I can still access my files using Ctrl + Alt + F2 and shut down but is there any way to fix this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is 'the answer' but I had a similar issue when I installed Ubuntu with the 'tmp' mount point set to a partition that did not have (and could not support) the appropriate permissions, ie. 1777. Once I changed the mount point to a more suitable partition the problem disappeared.